# Why my photo is not appearing when i host my website

Tags: html, image, version-control, project, document-root

I have created an online resume using VS Code with my photo on it. When I  "show preview" my resume on VS code there is a photo.

My problem is when I host my resume website on GitHub and try to visit the site, there is no photo on my resume. Is there something am doing wrong or am I missing something. Regards.

I have tried deleting the files and reloading them again hoping the problem will be solved but still I was not successful.

I tried to change the source of my photo on VS code but the problem is still there.

Comment: To further help you with your issue, do you mind sharing a screen shot or snippet of your code?

Comment: Hi. I did get help from a friend and the problem was solved. The issue was the source of the image.  The image source from the VS code was different from the one I had hosted the website. Regards